# IContextMenu Shell Extension for Phone Storage

Tags: winapi, shell-extensions

I have implemented context menu shell extension in Windows for files and folders.

However, I don't know how to make the menu appear on right clicking on phone storage (when plugging my Android phone or similar) such as Internal memory or SSD card.

Any ideas? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you means that you want to customize the context menu for the drive such as "D:\" after you connect the devices via usb, you can register the shell extension handler under:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

More detailed info about predefined shell objects, you can refer the link below:

[Predefined Shell Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers#predefined-shell-objects)

Comment: When an android phone is connected to Windows PC, it doesn't get a new drive letter. So a folder address is of type eg: This PC\Note 10\Internal Storage\Downloads. Since it uses MTP protocol to transfer files, we cannot see any of the file/folder context menu handlers registered under File/Folder/Drive key in registry. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. You also want to context menu customization also works for the folders in the **Internal Storage**, right?

Comment: Based on the predefined shell objects document, you can register the handler for all the files under subkey *, however it is not possible for the folder in the **Internal Storage**. If you want this feature, you can submit the feedback from Feedback Hub.